# How to serve static web content from S3 backed by multiple buckets from different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to serve static web content (HTML, CSS, and JS files) from S3 buckets. I know I can go to the bucket's properties tab and choose the item `Use this bucket to host a website` from the `Static website hosting` box. And I'm sure this step will still be part of the solution I'm looking for but it won't be all.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Deploying the same content to multiple regions and based on availability and/or latency, provide the service to the client.

As for the API Gateway, I know how to do this. I should create the same API Gateway (alongside underlying lambda functions) and Custom Domain Names in all the regions. And then creating the same domain on Route 53 (of type CNAME) and choose Latency as Routing Policy. One can also set up a Health Check for the Record Set so availability of the API Gateway and lambda functions are checked periodically.

Now I want to do the same for the S3 bucket and my static content. i.e. I want to deploy the same content to different regions and somehow make Route 53 to route the request to the **closest available** bucket. Previously, I was using CloudFront but it seems to me in this setup, I can only introduce one bucket.

Does anyone know how can I serve my static content from multiple buckets? If you are going to suggest CouldFront, please tell me how you plan to use multiple buckets.

Comment: Don't Reinvent The Wheel, use CloudFront

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate [a certificate](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/), setup a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to grab the content from your bucket and then point your domain to your distribution using Route53. You get free https and you can also add several S3 buckets as origins for your distribution.

[image]

From AWS Docs:

```
After you configure CloudFront to deliver your content, here's what happens when users request your objects:

1. A user accesses your website or application and requests one or more objects, such as an image file and an HTML file.

2. DNS routes the request to the CloudFront edge location that can best serve the request—typically the nearest CloudFront edge location in terms of latency—and routes the request to that edge location.

3. In the edge location, CloudFront checks its cache for the requested files. If the files are in the cache, CloudFront returns them to the user. If the files are not in the cache, it does the following:

3a. CloudFront compares the request with the specifications in your distribution and forwards the request for the files to the applicable origin server for the corresponding file type—for example, to your Amazon S3 bucket for image files and to your HTTP server for the HTML files.

3b. The origin servers send the files back to the CloudFront edge location.

3c. As soon as the first byte arrives from the origin, CloudFront begins to forward the files to the user. CloudFront also adds the files to the cache in the edge location for the next time someone requests those files.
```

P.D. Keep in mind this is for static content only!

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that I could introduce multiple `Origins` after I created the CloudFront instance. But still, I'm not sure what is the meaning of having multiple origins. Does it mean that if one of them is down, the other one will be used? Can you point me to some reference documentation saying exactly that?

Comment: CloudFront do not have regions, here are some docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html

Comment: Do you have any special region requirements? I would not worry about S3/Cloudfront being down. Hosting your static content/website this way is reliable; configuring regional endpoints is optimization/other special use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with CloudFront using Lambda@Edge to change origin based on answer from Route 53.

Please refer this blog for a sample Lambda@Edge code to do this -
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-multi-region-amazon-s3-origins/