# How to connect a domain name from third party DNS to AWS S3 Website with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, redirect, amazon-route53

I've hosted a static website in AWS S3 Bucket. I've registered my domain name with a third party DNS service https://yourhosting.nl. Can I connect my site with my Domain name properly? I've used redirecting service but it was showing my website in a `<iframe>` which causing problem for responsiveness of my website and for SEO also. 
What is the best way to host a static website in AWS without any responsive problem and SEO problems? Is it better to transfer my domains to Route 53? How many days it takes to transfer my domain to AWS Route 53?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Transferring the domain to Route53 probably won't help at all. The best way is going to be placing a CDN like CloudFront or CloudFlare in front of the S3 bucket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve static web content from S3 backed by multiple buckets from different regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169021/how-to-serve-static-web-content-from-s3-backed-by-multiple-buckets-from-differen)